# Django manage.py runserver is not working

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am facing problem while trying to start the server using the command

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

It is showing

```
C:\abc>python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
Validating models...

0 errors found
Django version 1.4.9, using settings 'abc.settings'
Development server is running at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

But cant access in browser via `http://127.0.0.1:8000`

It is showing :

```
Unable to connect

Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1:8000.

The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

But when I am trying the same by

```
python manage.py runserver
```

it is working fine. i can access the application `http://127.0.0.1:8000`

What can be the issue.

Comment: Strange it works for me while trying `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080` , not for `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` . Some issue with the port `8000` not sure if it is allocated by earlier `python manage.py runserver` which by default allocates `8000` port. Which I think should not be .

Comment: I'm not sure about the issue. You can access your site from http://0.0.0.0:8000 if you run your server as python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again? Don't get me wrong - maybe port 8000 is in use by a crashed run server on your "external IP"

Comment: If this is the case @init3 , then why `python manage.py runserver` is working fine , it is running on port `8000` , `http:\\127.0.0.1:8000`

Comment: binding 8000 to 0.0.0.0 (alias for e.g. 192.168.1.1) does not work. Binding 8000 to 127.0.0.1 (no alias) does work. Binding 8080 to 0.0.0.0 (e.g. 192.168.1.1) does work - not in use. That's why :)  Check `netstat -tulpn | grep 8000` to see if port 8000 is still in use by your external IP

Comment: Yes you are right @init3 tried this `C:\Users\15809>netstat -an

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:4105           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:4728           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:7163           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:47001          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING`

Comment: So I restarted my machine and those allocation of `8000 port` Binded with `0.0.0.0` by other external IP is gone and  this command `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` is working fine for me . Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Posted "official answer" - maybe I'll get a little up vote? :)

Comment: @ThomasSchwärlz: 0.0.0.0 is not an alias for 192.168.1.1. Rather, 0.0.0.0 is a wildcard to bind to all IP addresses that the machine has.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like Port 8000 is in use by your external IP. Please have a look if a process is running and kill it.

You can check the open ports with `netstat -a`. In Debian you get the PID with `netstat -tulpn | grep 8000`. The last line should display something like `1234/python`. Now kill it with `kill 1234`.

Alternative you could restart your system ;-)