# Django runserver not working from google cloud platform

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-platform

This question is very similar to (but is not the same because I am running on the google cloud, which I suspect may be cause of the issue):

- [Django runserver does not respond when opened in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582166/django-runserver-does-not-respond-when-opened-in-the-browser)
- [Django manage.py runserver is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21374912/django-manage-py-runserver-is-not-working)

I am trying to set up an api running on a VM-instance on the google cloud platform. So far I got nginx working (when I go to the ip address it greats me with a welcome message). When I run:

```
python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

I get the following output:

> Performing system checks...
>
> System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
>
> February 06, 2019 - 09:27:13
>
> Django version 2.1.5, using settings 'my_api.settings.development'
>
> Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
>
> Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

Which seems good, but when I go to any of the following pages (all of which I've listed under allowed_hosts):

- 0.0.0.0:8000
- 127.0.0.1:8000
- < my ip address>:8000

The page won't load.

I´ve tried checking which ports are used using

```
netstat
```

And I've killed all programs using this port after which I restarted my program, but to no avail.

At this point, I've fixed everything suggested in other posts and I'm out of ideas. What would be the next step in finding/solving the cause of my internet page not loading?

Comment: Did you open a firewall port for 8000? Where are you checking the ip addresses from? The address `0.0.0.0` is not a valid address to try to connect to. `127.0.0.1` is only valid from inside the VM.

Comment: @JohnHanley I did not, I am checking them from my own computer which could explain why they don't work. I'll have a look, thanks

Comment: @JohnHanley it was indeed a firewall port. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it. Otherwise I'll write it myself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to create a firewall rule to allow inbound traffic on `tcp port 8000`.

When creating the firewall rule, also specify a `Target tag` so that you can assign the firewall rule to the instance. Another option is to specify a service account such as `Compute Engine default service account` to assign the rule based upon identity.

[Filtering by service account vs. network tag](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#service-accounts-vs-tags)

Answer (score 0):

As @JohnHanley points out, I needed to create a firewall rule.

I did this by:

1. going to the google cloud platform console
2. firewall rules -> vpc network
3. + create firewall rule
4. Added all necessary ip addresses to the "source ip ranges" (followed with /32, not sure why, but this is what seems to work)
5. Under "Protocols and ports", I added tcp: 8000
6. I applied this to my server

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure http traffic is enabled
2. Make a firewall rule like so:

[image]